# Резкая анимация на iOS и Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

Я сделала анимацию при клике, и на компьютере она выглядит хорошо. Проблема в том что на iOS и Android девайсах анимация очень резкая, и выглядит рвано. Очень долго искала способы это исправить, но до сих пор не смогла найти решения. 
Вот мой JS, полностью код можно увидеть на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/146zatgp/16/).

```
$('.project-image').on('click', function() {
var $this = $(this);
var img = $(this).attr('id');
var minusLeft = $(this)[0].offsetLeft - 8;
var minusTop = $(this)[0].offsetTop - 80;

$('.show-description').fadeOut(600, function () {
    $('.hide-description').fadeIn(600);
});

$('.flex-container img').not('#' + img).animate({
    opacity: 0,
}, 200, "linear", function() {
  $this.css({
    top:'-'+minusTop+'px',
    left:'-'+minusLeft+'px'
    })

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.flex-container img').not('#'+img).hide();
    $this.css("position", 'static');
    $('.flex-container').css('flex-flow', 'column wrap');

    $('.'+img+'-text-block').show();
    $('.'+img+'-text-block').animate({
        opacity:1
      }, 100)
}, 600)
});

})

$('.hide-description').on('click', function() {

$('.hide-description').fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $('.show-description').fadeIn(1000);
});

$('[class*="-text-block"]').hide()
$('.flex-container').css('flex-flow', 'row wrap')
$('.flex-container img').css({
    position: 'relative',
    top:0,
    left:0
})
$('[class*="-text-block"]').css('opacity', '0');
$('.flex-container img').animate({
    opacity: 1,
}, 400)
$('.flex-container img').show()

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, для анимации всегда и везде желательно использовать только свойства `opacity` и `transform`. Тот кусок кода, который у вас отвечает за перемещение элементов стоит переписать на:

```
$this.css({
  transform: 'translate(' +minusLeft+ 'px, ' +minusTop+ 'px)'
})
```

...

```
$('.flex-container img').css({
  position: 'relative',
  transform: 'translate(0, 0)'
})
```

Во-вторых, используйте только последнюю версию jQuery, раз уж используете его — там метод `.animate()` норм оптимизирован.